# Local Model performance in Tensorflow Federated

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I am implementing federated learning through tensorflow-federated. The tutorial and all other material available compared the accuracy of the federated (global) model after each communication round. Is there a way I can compute the accuracy of each local model to compare against federated (global) model.

Summary:
Total number of clients: 15
For each communication round: Local vs Federated Model performance

References:

1. (https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/federated/blob/main/docs/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=blQGiTQFS9_r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how you can achieve this with `tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process` but I recommend you to take a look at [this simple fedavg implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/main/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg). Here you can use test_data -the same evaluation dataset you use in server model- for each client. I would suggest you to do `client_test_datasets = [test_data for x in sampled_train_ids]`. Then pass this as `iterative_process.next(server_state, sampled_train_data, client_test_datasets )`. Here you need to change the signatures for `run_one_round` and `client_update_fn` in the `simple_fedavg_tff.py`. In each case the signatures from test datasets shall be same as the ones for training dataset. Dont forget actually passing appropriate test datasets as input to each. Now move on to `simple_fedavg_tf.py` and change your `client_update`. Here you basically need to write evaluation very similar to one done for server model. Thereafter print the evaluation results if you wish or change the outputs for each level `(tf.function, tff.tf_computation, and tff.federated_computation)` and pass the eval results as output. If you go this way dont forget to update the output of `iterative_process.next`

edit: I assumed you wanted the accuracy of clients when the test dataset is the same as server test dataset.